# Как связать коды скомпилированные на c++ и c#

Tags: c#, c++, компиляция, компоновщик

Я задавал похожий а вопрос, но я спрашивал про компиляцию c++ вместе с c#. Немного разобравшись стало понятно, что компилирование двух кодов просто по определению невозможно. Но вот уже скомпилированные файлы можно как то связать линковщиком. Ключевые слова: ссылки, объектные файлы. Больше я ничего не понимаю и не могу конкретнее задать вопрос)

Comment: Вообще-то в один модуль не клеют натив и .net, делают разные модули, а взаимодействие по-разному. Можно на C++ сделать DLL и юзать ее через DllImport, можно COM/Active-X, можно TCP через локалхост, можно и не через локалхост; можно через файлы и т.д. Все обсуждалось тысячу раз.

Comment: Если проэкт ещё не создан - пишите на c++-cli

Comment: @SmInc клеют... Для этого и придумано понятие смешанной сборки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

1. Компилируете модуль С++ **cl.exe** с ключом /clr, получаете файл 1.obj
2. Компилируете модуль C# **csc.exe**, с ключом /addmodule:1.obj, получаете файл 2.netmodule
3. Затем скармливаете все полученное хозяйство (.obj и .netmodule) **link.exe**

Подробнее: [Sample: Mixing Unmanaged C++, C++/CLI, and C# code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/05/20/sample-mixing-unmanaged-c-ccli-and-c-code/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ссылку, но я не могу поверить что все так просто происходит). Получается достаточно указать нужные имена классов(функций, переменных?) и все будет работать? Т.е. как я понял есть определенный стандарт выходного файла при компиляции, и независимо от компилятора(нормального) структурное содержание obj файла на c++, будет таким же, как если бы его писали на c#?(тут понимаю, что код должен быть разным в виду разной работы c++  и c#, конкретно тут имелось ввиду что на c++ будут вручную написаны те же примочки, что и на c#)

Comment: @SergG на самом деле, я немного перепутал с алгоритмом, объектных файлов будет два (.obj для с++ и .netmodule для c#). Компилятор С++ с ключом /clr генерирует особый объектный файл; в отличие от обычного объектного файла он содержит метаданные, которые позволяют скомпоновать его с модулями .NET и получить на выходе управляемую сборку. Разумеется, чтобы код на С++ мог взаимодействовать с .NET-модулями, он должен использовать какой-то "клей" (в простейшем случае С++/CLI, но это может быть и COM), так как стандартный С++ не знает ничего про .NET

Comment: @SergG - _достаточно указать нужные имена ... и все будет работать?_ - Похоже, вы толком не смотрели ссылку. Вы должны на каждый неуправляемый класс написать управляемую обёртку на C++/CLI. А уже эту обёртку можно использовать в C#.